# Page publishes locally but not on gh-pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

So I've read [All my posts are gone! Where’d they go!](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#all-my-posts-are-gone-whered-they-go), and thought I had the right YAML on my post. It appears locally when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`. The date should be (of this writing), *yesterday* so I'm confused why something might believe it's in the future.

Here's my YAML 

`published: true
date: 2016-05-12 17:00:00 -0500`

Comment: Did you try to push again on gh-pages ?

Comment: Hmm... So when I first published it I got the timezone off by an hour and then might've edited that directly on github rather than locally and then pushing.
Could it be that gh-pages only rebuilds on a push and not a commit on github?